# How to keep simple data for all users to see

Tags: node.js, server

I am new to server side programming and need help with a problem I can't wrap my head around. For example on my website there is a counter and a button. On click the counter gets incremented, but it also needs to be incremented for all users currently on the website in real-time, and any future users.I am currently using web sockets for the real-time updating but once another user loads the page the counter is back to 0. How can I save the the counter into the HTML being served to new users? Is this possible with node.js? Should I be using another language to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, you can do this easily with node.js and websocket. If you want your click-counter to be persistent upon server restart, you'll also need to save it on server's disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with firebase cloud messaging service in simplest way. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Can this be used to change the HTML file that is being served?

Comment: yes. You can achieve whatever you want. It just call your js function when new message or notification triggers.